# Download a file and read from it in the same time

Tags: c#, .net

I download a file with this method:

```
WebClient WC = new WebClient();
WC.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
```

And i want that in the same time to read the file in the same time with:

```
var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

but i get allways :

```
The process cannot access the file 'filePath' because it is being used by another process.
```

It's possible to download and read in the same time?

## Edit

I now download the file with:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

                using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
                        int len;
                        while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And still get the error....

Comment: Does the file need to be written to disk? You could always just download it to memory and read the stream.

Comment: To do something *like* that you should probably use the raw `HttpWebRequest` / `GetResponseStream` and process each chunk as it arrives (via any of the "read" methods).

Comment: It's possible to download and write each chunk to a file?

Comment: @MTA you get a stream; as you read from the stream you can of course write each chunk to a receiving file-stream at the same time. That is *basically* what `WebClient` is making easier for you - it just wraps the raw request/response model and adds some common usage scenarios.

Comment: @MTA with your edit... did you open the file for write? it *looks* like you opened it for read (`FileAccess`)

Comment: After the edit is the download and it open for ReadWrite,and the upper fs is the place i need to read the file and it's FileAccess.Read

Comment: What if downloading the file using torrent (external software)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
        int len;
        while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))>0)
        {
            //Do with the content whatever you want
            // ***YOUR CODE*** 
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How should i define the filestream?

Comment: i define it like this: `var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);` . And still get the error

Comment: `The process cannot access the file filePath because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: @MTA this means -as error says- another application uses this file. Close that application or use a different filename

Comment: But the other application is where i try to download the file

Comment: @MTA above code downloads and saves the file in chunks. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I try to download a file with the code you give me and then try to read it in the same time from another thread with this: `var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);` . And when i try to read i get this error.

Comment: @MTA don't read it from another thread, you already have the data. See the comment. `//Do with the content whatever you want`. put your code there. You have the `buffer` and `len`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.domain.com/file.txt");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 8192)) > 0)
{
    // handle your raw data
    // you needed raw data = buffer[0 to bytesRead - 1]

}
stream.Close();
response.Close();
```