# Download to file and save to byte array

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to download a file to my computer and in the same time save it to Byte Array:

```
try
{
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);

    using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
            int len;
            while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                //Do with the content whatever you want
                // ***YOUR CODE*** 

                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                if (len > 0)
                {
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                    len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }

                file = memoryStream.ToArray();
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }

    fileStream.Close();
}
catch (Exception exc) { }
```

And i noticed that it's not download all the file with this.

I wan to do it because i want to download a file and in the same time work with it.
Any idea why this problem happen?

Comment: that code does not make sense...

Comment: Also, it seems a dup of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951621/download-a-file-and-read-from-it-in-the-same-time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278986/download-a-file-over-http-into-a-byte-array-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be double-reading - you are putting different things into the memory-stream / file-stream - it should be more like:

```
// declare file/memory stream here
while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
      memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
      fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
      // if you need to process "len" bytes, do it here
}
```

You might be able to lose "memoryStream" completely if you are processing the "len" bytes  immediately. If it fits in-memory,  it may be easier to just use WebClient.DownloadData and then File.WriteAllBytes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to get the file bytes by using the `System.Net.WebClient.WebClient()`:

```
private static byte[] DownloadFile(string absoluteUrl)
{
   using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
   {
      return client.DownloadData(absoluteUrl);
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var bytes = DownloadFile(absoluteUrl);
```